# how to find all the values of fields in WIQL TFS Workitem by C# code ?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, wiql

how to find all the Values of Field such as Done status,Workitemtype and state
Image attached.
**workitem type fields with it's values** 
[image]  
**State field with all it's value's** 

 [image] 
**Done status with it's value's** 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use client API to get allowedvalues by getting an instance of class **FieldDefinition** and referencing the **AllowedValues** property.

*[FieldDefinition.AllowedValues Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.fielddefinition.allowedvalues(v=vs.120).aspx)*

A sample code for your reference.

```
var tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("http://vstspioneer:8080/tfs/VSTSDF");
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var allowedValues = workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[xxx.xxx].AllowedValues;

foreach (String value in allowedValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Done status is not a build-in filed, should be a customize field.

More details please refer this blog:  [Get List of Allowed Values in TFS Work Item Field](http://c-sharpe.blogspot.sg/2009/12/get-list-of-allowed-values-in-tfs-work.html)

Comment: how to get Filter the Allowedvalue on the basis of a Project let's say i want assigned to allowed values of scrum project only.